# SUM in access query

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, ms-access-2010

I have a Table **(T_agents)** of agents each has a number of call in a field called **NCH** I want to create another field call **NCHpercent** that is the percentage of calls taken by that agent. So the formula is ***NCH/Total NCH***.
So in the query builder I have the following and formula but it dosent work :(

```
NCHpercent: [NCH.T_agents] / ( SUM(SELECT [NCH.T_agents] FROM [T_agents]) )
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

This would be easier if we could see the table structure as that impacts everything.  However I hope I follow this correctly, but I imagine your table (T_agents) as something like:

```
+-------+-------------+------+
| ID    | Agents      | NCH  |
+-------+-------------+------+
| 1     | agent_1     | 1    | 
| 1     | agent_1     | 1    | 
| 1     | agent_2     | 2    | 
| 1     | agent_3     | 1    | 
+-------+-------------+------+
```

Now assuming that is correct (and NCH is not a unique ID but a total number of calls then we can use a query like this to calculate percentage - note this is not stored in a table, this is just to display the percentage value in a query- I've also added the sum of the total in for the sake of it:

```
SELECT SUM([T_Agents].NCH) AS total_SUM, [T_agents].Agents, ((SUM(T_agents.NCH))/(select SUM(t_agents.NCH )from T_agents)*100) AS NCHPercent
FROM T_agents
GROUP BY [t_agents].Agents;
```

In my test the results would be:

```
2, agent_1, 40
2, agent_2, 40
1, agent_3, 20
```

However if I got this wrong and the NCH column is in fact

Comment: I am trying to get the percentage of Number of Calls Handle per row so i need to get the number of calls hadle in a row and divide with the total of number of calls hadle by all the agents here are 2 links of the table on working with: [Query](http://chiham.com/SOF/query.jpg) and [Table](http://chiham.com/SOF/T_agents.jpg)

Comment: You got us confused of your table names, column names and queries. So is your table called T_agents or AHT_Tenure?. What is the name of the column that has the agents? what is the source of data for that column?

Answer (score -1):

Ok. I just found the answer soing some trial an error. The answer is this code:

```
NCHperc: [AHT_Tenure].[Calls Handled]/(SELECT Sum(AHT_Tenure.[Calls Handled]) AS [SumaDeCalls Handled]
FROM AHT_Tenure)
```

By the way thank you guys. And actually the agents name dosent matter for this query since all I wanted was the percentage on each row.